# XMLHttpRequest.responseText doesnt write the value when calling a URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

There may be a small error in my code. please advice me.

I want to call a URL and display the value in div on pageload.I wrote this code from SO but the responseText doesnt write the value in the div element's innerhtml

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    
 var req ;
// Browser compatibility check          
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

 try {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 } catch (e) {

   try {
     req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e) {}
 }

}


var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "www.example.com/Default.aspx?usrname=john",true);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "My Status: " + req.responseText;
}

req.send(null);
</script>
 <html>
 <head/>
 <body>
 <div id="divTxt"></div></body>
 </html>
```

> The output I get is
>    My status :

PS: I want this to be done after pageload and The url returns a value "online" when called manually

**EDIT** 
This is the code I referred : [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906876/call-a-url-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot ajax a url from another domain unless it has implemented [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

If you need to get data from somewhere which is not *same origin* you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Also to debug, try calling the url from the locationbar to see if you receive valid data for your request

Answer (score 0):

req.onreadystatechange = function () {
   document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "My Status: " + req.responseText;
}

you have to check, if the request was successful:

if (req.readyState === 4) {
   // what should be done with the result
}

finally, it has to look like this:

req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "My Status: " + req.responseText;
    }
}

Comment: sorry for the bad markup. i'm not firm with the forum-syntax, yet ;)

Comment: @mightyplow , from where does this reqObj comes from? After I modified the code like you said, it shows nothing as output whereas previously it showed My status:

Comment: there was a mistake in my previous code. i changed it. the variable respObj is given to the eventHandler by the browser.
i'm goin to test you're complete snippet right now and i'll give you back the correct one...

Comment: @mightyplow, I checked with your updated code but still it shows nothing as output

Comment: ah sorry. i did something wrong... you were completely right. forget what i did with the respObj stuff.
it is req.readystate === 4 and req.responseText. sorry for the stolen time

Comment: @mightyplow, now it looks like my original output. i.e) My Status: , the reponseText doesnt show the output

Comment: how do you give back the result by the server? maybe you use "return" instead of "echo"?

Comment: hmm... i just saw, you're not using php. don't know how it works in your case. it seems like the return method of the server isn't right.