# Call a URL and get the return value. both Jquery and Javascript doesnt display the return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XMLHttpRequest.responseText doesnt write the value when calling a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235452/xmlhttprequest-responsetext-doesnt-write-the-value-when-calling-a-url)

I ve written the code in both javascript and jquery to call a URL and get the return value by **referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906876/call-a-url-from-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call).**

But the return value of the aspx page doesnt get displayed in my html file. Since I am new to javascript and jquery, can you please let me know if I need to put a call back as its cross posting? if so, can you explain me?

**The Javascript code is**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >    
 var req ;
 // Browser compatibility check          
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

 try {
 req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 } catch (e) {

 try {
 req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 } catch (e) {}
 }

}


var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?usrname=john",true);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "My Status: " + req.responseText;
}

req.send(null);
</script>

</script>
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<div id="divTxt"></div></body>
</html>
```

> **The output I get is : My Status** :

**The JQuery code is**

```
 var html = $.ajax({
 url: "http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?usrname=john",
 async: true
 }).responseText;
 document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "My Status: " + html;
```

**The output I get is blank page**

PS: I am [reposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235452/xmlhttprequest-responsetext-doesnt-write-the-value-when-calling-a-url) the question again as my question was not answered properly before.

**

**> EDIT: in my original code, there is**

> http://

**

Comment: @coder323 : is it a cross domain request ??

Comment: @Furqan, Yes its a cross domain request

Comment: @alex, I have admitted in my first post itself, I am reposting it as my question was not answered

Comment: @Coder323 You may have admitted it, but an intentional duplicate is still frowned upon.

Comment: @coder please finish the other question. I have copied my answer there.

Comment: @alex, sorry, I wanted a solution as that post went unnoticed by many

Comment: @mplungjan, I closed the other question with your answer

Comment: Thanks. This one will be closed too since it is a duplicate

Comment: @mplungjan, can you please guide me how should I get a solution if my question goes unnoticed ? (I asked that during weekends)

Comment: Nothing really. In a few days you can create a bounty if you have enough rep. It works for simple questions. In your case there are almost 5000 similar or identical questions at SO which all tell you, you cannot ajax a url from same domain, so a good search before you ask is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot ajax a url from another domain unless it has implemented [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

If you need to get data from somewhere which is not *same origin* you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Also to debug, try calling the url from the locationbar to see if you receive valid data for your request

Comment: @mplungjan, In my original url, http is there. I tried calling from the browser and it returns the value correctly

Comment: @Coder then it is a simple matter of cross domain access which is not possible with ajax unless you do something specific at the server

Comment: @mplungjan, so I need to write a script in the server to return a value as its cross domain?

Comment: @Coder323 either write a server side script, or if possible use jsonp which will allow cross-domain ajax calls.

Comment: @mplungjan & @Ben Rowe , I will try jsonp to allow cross domain ajax or server side script. Thanks

Comment: @Coder - yes, you need a so-called proxy if the site you are trying to access does not have a JSONP api.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing several things incorrectly.

First, you're overwriting your req variable (which you initialize for different browsers up on top).  So, remove this line: var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

Next you're calling a url that is at a different domain than yours which AJAX security won't let you.  Also you're forgetting to include http:// but that is besides the point since you're not allowed to leave your own domain, and lastly you're calling onReadyState change but failing to note the readyState which will go through several stages. You're looking for stage 4 to actually do something with.

Comment: I also tried if (req.readyState == 4) but still it didnt work