# How can I get YouTube embeded video title from id using plain javascript in 2020?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Requirements:

1. Plain Javascript, only.
2. NO Google API account.
3. Code that works today.

I'm struggling for hours searching answers here and elsewhere to no avail.
The answers are either too old (BTW, no way to filter them for a date!?!) and thus not working, or they are written in PHP, Jquery, Bash, etc.

I find it extremely ironical to being able to embed a video based on an ID easily, play the video, control it, but no way to get its title using Javascript!?!?

The reason I need the title to be acquired automatically is to increase the efficiency in filling a database built with HTML and Javascript.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by  ID? An example please.

Comment: Let's say: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfZzvOe3Ae0
Id is gfZzvOe3Ae0. I already have extracted the video ID from URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can call: `http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXXXXXXX`
This call will return text that needs to be parsed. This response contains all info about the video including the title.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the code from the last answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906876/call-a-url-from-javascript to call the URL and got a cross-origin error.
Video is allowed, info is not?